# Trying to enable a disabled button when a textfield is not empty

Tags: javascript

So im just trying to enable a button when 3 text fields are not empty,and disable the button again if they become empty.Right now I was only trying it with one field just to get it working first but cant get it to work and no idea why.Would appreciate any help

```
     <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkEnableSubmit() {
           if ( completePurchaseForm.address.value != "") 
          {document.getElementById("button").disabled = false;}
      }
       </script>




        <form action="RegServlet" name="completePurchaseForm" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> Address  : </td><td> <input name="address" onkeyup="checkEnableSubmit()" id="address" size=100 type="text" /> </td> 
                </tr>
                                    <tr>
                    <td> Card Type  : </td><td> <input name="cardType" id="cardType" size=15 type="text" /> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Card Number  : </td><td> <input name="cardNumber" id="cardNumber" size=15 type="text" /> </td> 
                </tr>
            </table>

            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="completePurchase" />
            <input type="button" disabled name="submit" value="Complete your purchase" />
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add id to your button `<input type="button" id="button1">` to use `document.getElementById("button1")`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<input name="address" onkeyup="checkEnableSubmit()" id="address" size=100 type="text" />
        <input name="cardType" onkeyup="checkEnableSubmit()" id="cardType" size=15 type="text" /> 
<input name="cardNumber" onkeyup="checkEnableSubmit()" id="cardNumber" size=15 type="text" /> 
<input type="button" disabled name="submit" value="Complete your purchase" id="button" />
```

and this:

```
function checkEnableSubmit() {
var valid = true;
       if ( completePurchaseForm.address.value != "") 
valid = flase;
       if ( completePurchaseForm.cardType.value != "") 
valid = flase;
       if ( completePurchaseForm.cardNumber.value != "") 
valid = flase;
      document.getElementById("button").disabled = valid;
  }
```